# How to do wildcard queries with Solr PointFields

Tags: solr

I'm building a new schema and I'm trying to use the new `solr.IntPointField` instead of `solr.TrieIntField`.

Everything is good so far except that I can't search for all documents with any value for a specific field.

Normally I would do `foo:*` but it's not returning any results.

Here's my schema

```
<fields>
       <field name="foo" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
</fields>

<types> 
    <fieldType name="pint" class="solr.IntPointField" docValues="true"/>docValues="true" />
     ...
</types>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual syntax to find any document that has a value for the given field is `foo:[* TO *]`. It should also work for the point types.

Comment: Do you know why foo:* is accepted and doesn't throw an error?